# Highlight Polygons on a map Arcgis API for Javascript

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am able to query a feature layer using the following code

```
          var query = new Query();
          var geometry = null;
          query.returnGeometry = true;
          query.outFields = ["*"];
          query.where = "CONST LIKE '%"+searchString+"%'";
         resultsLayer.queryFeatures(query).then(function(results){
              var resultsArray = results.features;
              console.log(); 
          });
```

However after collecting the results I would like to be highlighting the returned features on the mapView. The results however didn't return a 'graphics' attribute for me to add to the map layer which is why I am stuck.

How do I add features to the mapView using the returned features array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a good [example](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/233892/arcgis-javascript-api-drawing-graphics-from-a-feature-layer-query-not-appearing/234059#234059) as an answer to my own question.  Each feature in `results.features` should have its own geometry.  If you know that it is a polygon geometry, you can instantiate a new polygon like so: `new Polygon{rings:feature.geometry.rings})`.  This is a valid graphic to add to a graphics layer.