# ArcGIS Javascript API Drawing graphics from a feature layer query not appearing in graphics layer

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm trying to draw the features resulting from a query of a feature layer onto a graphics layer.

```
var query = abstracts.createQuery();
query.where = "ANUM = '1'";
query.returnGeometry = true;
var rl = map.findLayerById("graphics");
abstracts.queryFeatures(query).then(function (results) {
    rl.removeAll();
    var features = results.features.map(function (graphic) {
        graphic.symbol = new SimpleLineSymbol({
            size: 6.5,
            color: "darkorange"
        });
        return graphic;
    });
    rl.addMany(features);
});
```

When I set a breakpoint before the last line(rl.addMany(features)), I see that features contains the expected feature, and the symbol is set properly.  Also, I know that the feature exists, but is not appearing on the map.  Also, below is my declaration of feature layer and graphics layer.

```
        var abstracts = new FeatureLayer({
            url: "@arcgisServerServiceUrl/" + featureLayerId,
            outFields: ["*"],
            visible:false,
            mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
            maxScale: 0,
            minScale: 290000,
            renderer: renderer,
        });

        var resultsLayer = new GraphicsLayer({id:"graphics"});

        map.layers.addMany([
            abstracts,
            resultsLayer,
        ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer why what I did above didn't work, but I can give the answer I found.  For each feature in `results.features` above:

```
  var polygon = new Polygon({
    rings: feature.geometry.rings
  });

  var lineSymbol = new SimpleLineSymbol({
    color: [226, 119, 40],
    width: 4
  });

  var polygonGraphic = new Graphic({
    geometry: polygon,
    symbol: lineSymbol
  });

 resultsLayer.add(polygonGraphic);
```